# Radio checked validation failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a strange problem here with (un)checked radio buttons.

My code:

```js
function validate(el) {
    if ($('#type_P').is(':checked') === true && (parseInt($('#voucher_price').val()) <= 0) || isNaN(parseInt($('#voucher_price').val()))) {
        alert($('#type_P').is(':checked') === true);
        $('#service_price').addClass('error');
        $('#service_price').parent().addClass('error');
    }

    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    P: <input type="radio" checked name="type" id="type_P" value="P">
    S: <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_S" value="S">

    <input id="voucher_price">
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

And it returns me 'false' in alert when 'type_S' is checked, not 'type_P'. I mean no alert has to be shown.

Why? How is possible to show this alert when the same condition is in the if statement?

Comment: Looks like you're missing (or have incorrect) brackets around the `||` - as it is, it's: if (checked and <=0) *or* voucher is NaN

Comment: Because you if statement has an OR condition. If the initial part is falsy the second part can still be truthy. In your scenario when `isNaN(parseInt($('#voucher_price').val()))` is evaluated to a truthy value, the alert always shows. (eg. when the `#voucher_price` is empty or contains a non-number) `expr1 && expr2 || expr3` is evaluated as `(expr1 && expr2) || expr3` not as `expr1 && (expr2 || expr3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments under question said, there was a problem in brackets. Right is `(expr1 && (expr2 || expr3))`, I had `(expr1 && expr2 || expr3)`. It was just a typo from me. Thanks for both commentators.

Nothing special, I just need to answer this question to move it from the 'unanswered' list to avoid another people lose their time on it.